How to migrate my project from one DC to another DC using Catalyst CLI?
I have a Catalyst project in US DC which I wish to migrate to IN DC since US DC doesn't have Zia Identity Scanner which is vital for my use case, can someone help me on this? Is there a CLI command to migrate project from one DC to another DC?

To migrate your Catalyst project from one DC to another DC you can use IaC(Infrastructure as Code) feature from Catalyst to export your project from US DC as zip file using IaC Export and import the project from that zip in your IN DC account using IaC Import. You can refer to the official documentation here.
You can also perform this project import/export from Catalyst CLI using the CLI commands "catalyst iac:export" and "catalyst iac:import". You can refer to the official help documentation for the same here.
